# Is there any way to set default Podcast display order in iTunes 12.5?

Tags: itunes, settings, podcasts

I have to set each individual podcast to "oldest to newest" when I would like this as a default.

This would not be such a big issue except that iTunes unsubscribes me from an average of one podcast a day - anyone know why that happens?  (these are active podcast with current episodes and current listening activity).  Certain podcasts get unsubscribed about once a week - others are random.